# XHR Request to file sitting in folder protected by .htaccess (Auth Basic)

Tags: javascript, php, apache

This one is driving me nuts.

Been around in circles with both SO and non-SO answers.

## Overview

Making XHR (cross-origin) using **vanilla** Javascript from ***localhost*** to ***remote***  PHP script which returns an array (JSON).

### Files

#### local.js

```
  var xhrGetArray = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://example.com/ajax/target_script.php";
  var params = "t=" + Math.random();

  xhrGetArray.open("POST", url, true);  

  xhrGetArray.send(params);
```

#### .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://thelocalhostname    
</ifModule>
```

#### target_script.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array_to_return);
exit;
?>
```

**All goes well and origin working as expected.**

However, I want to password protect (Auth Basic) the folder which the file is sitting in, prompting the user to enter *or* sending the Auth credentials in the XHR.

when i add the standard AUTH code to the .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

**so .htaccess becomes:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
require valid-user 

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://thelocalhostname    
</ifModule>
```

**I then get the ORIGIN error:** (Chrome Dev)

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://thelocalhostname' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401
```

## I have tried the following:

**added this to the XHR (local.js):**

```
xhrGetOnlineOrders.withCredentials = true;
xhrGetOnlineOrders.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("user:pass"));
```

**entered Auth credentials manually and then tried the request**

Been going round in circles for hours with this one, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

I tried (thanks to CBRoe - i did have it in there at some point during the circles i am going around in) adding the following to the .htaccess file **and** the PHP file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

and it still says:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present
```

Yet, the SET HEADER is present in the .htaccess

## Further update

When I remove the AUTH code from the .htaccess file the response from the server includes the "origin" data.

It is literally when I add the AUTH code that things fail - for some reason with the AUTH code present the server is not sending the "origin" header back.

Comment: You need to allow credentials from the server-side as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials

Comment: Thanks CBroe - I tried adding **Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true** to the .htaccess and still the same issue. It still tells me that there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Comment: I’d try adding those headers from inside the PHP script first, instead of on server configuration level and possibly without any restriction.

Comment: Thanks again CBroe, Tried but no luck. Driving me nuts this one :o(

Comment: Updated question